# SQL injection to drop table

Tags: sql-injection

Is it possible to perform a drop table injection on the following code?

---

```
EmpTable result = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<EmpTable>("Select * from EmpTable where username = '" + TxtUsername.Text + "'and password = '" + TxtPassword.Text + "'").FirstOrDefault();
```

---

i have already tried putting values like:

---

```
';drop table EmpTable;--
```

but whenever i put ; anywhere, the query doesn't executes at all.

please help, i am a starter

Comment: Does db user has permission to drop tables?

Comment: If the db user has all permissions, the code will drop it

Comment: yes there are no  permision limits set. still it doesnt works

Comment: go to ServerExplorer -> new Query -> and write "drop table Emptable" to see what happens

Comment: It drops, i've also tried [EmpTable result = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<EmpTable>("drop table EmpTable")] works fine

Comment: Is there any way possible to include drop table inside the query without using ;?

Comment: Don’t you get some kind of error message?